# Error: No connection options were found in any orm configuration files

Tags: node.js, typescript, oracle, typeorm

I want connect to oracle with typeorm

```
createConnection().then(async connection => {
    const app = express();
    const userRepository = getRepository(User);
    const users = await userRepository.find();
    console.log(users);   
    app.listen(3000);
}).catch(error => console.log("xxx",error));
```

[image]

`ormconfig.json` is in `./Myproject/ormconfig.json` but say error :Error: No connection options were found in any orm configuration files.

With these settings , I was already connected to the database with the oracledb.

Please help me

**UPDATE**

I generate project with this `typeorm init --name MyProject --database oracle`.
This is typeorm default structure.

Answer (score 9):

Hello I had the same error for one day, but I had to explicitly show the path of the config file
This was my current `typeorm` `package.json` script command

`"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"`

i changed it to

`"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/config/postgres.config.ts"`

not how I explicitly set the path of the config file that I am using, no matter which extension you are using, either `.js`, `.ts`, or `.json`

here is the example of my config file

```js
// postgres.config.ts

import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export const pgConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: parseInt(<string>process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  entities: ['dist/src/modules/**/entities/*.entity.js'],
  synchronize: true,
  migrations: ['dist/src/db/migrations.js'],
  cli: { migrationsDir: 'src/db/migrations' },
};
```

Hope it gonna help

Answer (score 2):

From the picture you posted, you misplaced the `ormconfig.json` in ./src directory which path maybe `your_project/src/ormconfig.json`.Please move it to root directory of project(path: `your_project/ormconfig.json`) will work out!

Comment: I moved ormconfig.json to  ./src directory but it still gives an error

Comment: root not ./src! The current file path maybe `your_project/src/ormconfig.json`.You should move it to `your_project/ormconfig.json` @ashkufaraz

Comment: In the image ormconfig.josn is in the root directory(MyProject/ormconfig.json)

Comment: No, it's not. It's in `./src`. You have to move it one level up.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use the following instead

```
npx typeorm migration:create -n migrationName
```

Comment: This only works for creating migration files and not actually running the migrations.

Answer (score -2):

I've experienced this a few times and I noticed that it's some caching issues.
Here're a few things you could do:

Option 1:

- Delete your `node_modules/` folder and reinstall.

Option 2:

- Restart your editor (I'm using vscode)